# What does "context" file mean in jetty world

Tags: java, embedded-jetty

I am following this tutorial instruction: http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/spnego-support.html

It says the following: `A corresponding UserRealm needs to be created either programmatically if embedded, via the jetty.xml or in a context file for the webapp.`

Now I am using embedded jetty and I could create a `web.xml` using the `WebAppContext` and \jee but what is the `context` file? Is it talking about something like a Spring context?

(I am fairly new to Java)

Comment: web.xml file of your application.

Comment: @SanjayRajjadi - that doesn't make much sense because it talks about the `web.xml` file earlier.

Comment: https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/jetty-11/operations-guide/index.html#og-deploy-jetty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With *context file for the webapp*, they probably mean the jetty.xml configuration file, which can also be used on a per-app basis, when you name it `jetty-web.xml` and place it in your WEB-INF directory (alongside the web.xml configuration file).

Frame of a jetty-web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure.dtd">
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <!-- configuration here -->
</Configure>
```

You can configure your realms with it, e.g.:

```
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  <Set name="contextPath">/test</Set>
  <Set name="war"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/webapps/test</Set>
  <Get name="securityHandler">
    <Set name="loginService">
      <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.HashLoginService">
            <Set name="name">Test Realm</Set>
            <Set name="config"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/etc/realm.properties</Set>
      </New>
    </Set>
  </Get>
</Configure>
```

For details, see:

https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Reference/jetty-web.xml

https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Realms

Since you are using embedded jetty, I am unsure if you can configure user realms using the normal `jetty-web.xml` configuration, or if you have to set them up programmatically.

I did this programmatically, but with an older (6.1) version of Jetty. But I also have used the `jetty-web.xml` in an embedded jetty to configure some parameters, e.g. the upload file size limit.

Comment: How does this differ from `web.xml` which has a root of `<web-app>`

Comment: The web.xml is the standard configuration for Java web applications, you define servlets, servlet mappings, welcome pages, listeners, filters etc. with it. The jetty-web.xml is a configuration specific for Jetty. Other web servers may share the same web.xml, as it is a standard, but may be configured differently for server specific tasks.

Comment: Ah right!!! So I wouldn't need both a `web.xml` and a `jetty-web.xml` as as everything in `web.xml` can go in `jetty-web.xml`...right?

Comment: No, they are entirely different. You have a web.xml which configures your web app in a general way and which can be parse by every J2EE Container. The jetty-web.xml will only be read by Jetty and can be used to configure the Jetty parameters, which can't be set through web.xml.